# Using variables into viewbox

Tags: javascript, html, typescript, viewbox

I'm working with svg class and a `viewbox`. Inside this `viewbox`, of the HTML, I wan't to use a variables that is in a typescript but I retrieve an error that says:

`<svg>` attribute `viewBox`: Expected number

As I calculate this variable, I'm trying to understand how can I give it to the `viewbox`. Here is my code:

radial.ts

```
sizeCircle: number = parseInt(this._size);
```

radial.html

```
< svg class = "svg" viewbox = "0 0 sizeCircle sizeCircle"
[style.width.px] = "sizeCircle"
```

If I insert a number inside, of course it will work but I must to call this variable from the .ts. Is there a workaround I can apply?

Comment: `sizeCicle` is used instead of `sizeCircle`. Besides, is there any javascript framework there? if so, you should either do: `viewbox="0 0 {{sizeCircle}} {{sizeCircle}}"` or `[viewbox]="'0 0 ' + sizeCircle + ' ' + sizeCircle"` Otherwise a **string** will be evaluated instead of the expected value.

Comment: I'm sorry. I missed a letter when I wrote the code. I tryed with your code but I receive:
Can't bind to 'viewbox' since it isn't a known property of ':svg:svg'

For both cases. Did I put the code in the wrong place? I put both of them (one at the time) in the html, instead of "0 0 sizeCircle..."

Answer (score 0):

Okay. After few hours I solve the problem. Here is the solution I did:

```
const iSize = parseInt(this.size);

svg.setAttribute('viewBox', '0 0 ' + iSize + ' ' + iSize);
```

Everything in the .ts. I remove all the code from the html and it works now